# Absolute transparent web browser control, is it possible?

Tags: wpf, webbrowser-control

I'm creating a desktop Winforms or WPF app, but I'm using HTML/JS/CSS to create UI. So the simpliest solution is using a Web Browser control in a host window.

I want an absolute transparent web browser control now. 
For example, I have DIV with 50% transparency, then I should see the Windows desktop icons through the DIV (The host form and web browser control should be transparent).

Is it possible?

Comment: Desktop applications are not HTML. If you're doing a desktop application, use relevant desktop technology instead.

Comment: It used to be possible (more or less), but was removed in .NET 4.5: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2644120-bring-back-the-hwndhost-isredirected-and-compositi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here are several possibilities**

1. If you do not care about the size of browser window, you can set the `Width` and `Height` to `0`.
2. If you want to have a specified browser window size, you can set the `Left` equals `-Width` and `Top` equals `-Height`.
3. Set the `Parent` of browser control to `Null`, so that the browser control will become invisible as well.

I prefer the second solution.

Comment: The DIV lives in the web browser control. If the webbrowser control's width and height are zero, will the DIV be visible?

Comment: Do you mean, if the size of browser canvas is shrinked to 0, no DIVs will be rendered actually due to browser optimization? Please see my updated answer.